# Updated how can i edit my script to import additionnal fields to mailchimp

Tags: powershell, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

hi and sorry for my errors

now i have problem with fields, actually instead of having : firstname, lastname, email fields, business asking me to have 2 additionnal fields, job and country and i've updated my script with this :

```
$person = @{
  email_address=$email
  status ="subscribed"
  merge_fields = @{
    FNAME=$firstname
    LNAME=$lastname
    title=$title
    Country=$country

         
$dayAgo = (Get-Date).AddDays(-5).Date
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter {whenCreated -ge $dayAgo} -Properties whenCreated, StartDate, country, title
# Iterates over each user in AD that is new

Foreach ($user in $users) {
    $flagDown = $false
    echo $user
    $Fname = $user.GivenName
    $Lname = $user.surname
    $email = $user.UserPrincipalName 
    $title = $user.title
    $country = $user.country
    addUsertoMailChimp $email $Fname $Lname $title $country
}
```

and my problem now is , there is no data pulling in mailchimp, i mean i have firstname, lastname, and email but i don't have country and job

Thank you in advance

Comment: I probably means that you specified the wrong `$url`

Comment: Please [update the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63811596/edit) with relevant information (as you can see, code doesn't format well in comments)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  i updated the post, thank you for helping me

Comment: I re-formatted your code slightly (without changing any syntactical element), but it looks like something is missing - `$person` hashtable is unclosed (missed a couple of `}`s?), and the function definition for `addUsertoMailChimp` is nowhere to be found

Comment: hi mathias, i can send you directly the whole code if you want

Comment: If you just copy-paste it as-is at the [bottom of the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63811596/edit) I'll help you format it